# Loop through all levels and use each level value as a filter for defining a new variable

Tags: r, purrr

Here is a subset of features in my modeling work flow:

```
 model_ranger %>% select(splits, id, mtry, mae)
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   splits            id     mtry   mae
   <named list>      <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 <split [72K/18K]> Fold1     1  261.
 2 <split [72K/18K]> Fold1     2  265.
 3 <split [72K/18K]> Fold2     1  278.
 4 <split [72K/18K]> Fold2     2  281.
 5 <split [72K/18K]> Fold3     1  258.
 6 <split [72K/18K]> Fold3     2  262.
 7 <split [72K/18K]> Fold4     1  291.
 8 <split [72K/18K]> Fold4     2  295.
 9 <split [72K/18K]> Fold5     1  289.
10 <split [72K/18K]> Fold5     2  295.
```

That was for training a ranger random forest on 5 folds with two values of mtry to try with.

I have several objects like the one above, I have a similar one for a model I tried on the same folds using xgboost:

```
model_xgb %>% select(splits, id, nrounds, mae)
# A tibble: 15 x 4
   splits            id    nrounds   mae
   <named list>      <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 <split [72K/18K]> Fold1     100  262.
 2 <split [72K/18K]> Fold1     150  262.
 3 <split [72K/18K]> Fold1     200  262.
 4 <split [72K/18K]> Fold2     100  278.
 5 <split [72K/18K]> Fold2     150  278.
 6 <split [72K/18K]> Fold2     200  278.
 7 <split [72K/18K]> Fold3     100  258.
 8 <split [72K/18K]> Fold3     150  258.
 9 <split [72K/18K]> Fold3     200  258.
10 <split [72K/18K]> Fold4     100  291.
11 <split [72K/18K]> Fold4     150  291.
12 <split [72K/18K]> Fold4     200  291.
13 <split [72K/18K]> Fold5     100  290.
14 <split [72K/18K]> Fold5     150  290.
15 <split [72K/18K]> Fold5     200  290.
```

I would like to compare each model and each variation of each model side by side across the 5 folds on mae.

What I'm currently doing is this:

```
model_list <- list(
  model_ranger_mtry_1 = model_ranger %>% filter(mtry == 1),
  model_ranger_mtry_2 = model_ranger %>% filter(mtry == 2),
  model_xgb_nrounds_100 = model_xgb %>% filter(nrounds == 100),
  model_xgb_nrounds_150 = model_xgb %>% filter(nrounds == 150),
  model_xgb_nrounds_200 = model_xgb %>% filter(nrounds == 200)
)

# compare models
model_list %>% 
  imap(~tibble(
    model_name = .y,
    mae = mean(.x$mae),
    rmse = mean(.x$rmse)
  )) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

This works. I see average mae for each model type and variant.

My question is, rather than manually typing each variation in model list e.g.

```
  model_ranger_mtry_1 = model_ranger %>% filter(mtry == 1),
  model_ranger_mtry_2 = model_ranger %>% filter(mtry == 2),
```

Is there a clever short hand way of doing this? Where, for each variation I would define a list element. From ranger through to xgboost, where the first uses mtry as a variant to filter on then get the mean while for the xgb one to get each variation of nrounds, filter on that variation then get the mean. etc.

Or is what I'm already doing the simplest way? It seems manual and prone to error if I make changes to any tuning parameters.

Comment: You can ddo `model_ranger %>% group_split(mtry)` and `model_xgb %>% group_split(nrounds)` Or may be have a `group_by` operation i.e. `bind_rows(model_ranger, model_xgb %>% select(mtry = nrounds)) %>% group_by(mtry) %>% .`

Comment: Hi Akrun, thanks for the pointers. I tried adding some of those e.g. `model_ranger <- model_ranger %>% group_split(mtry)` which results in "Error in UseMethod("group_split") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_split' applied to an object of class "list""

`class(model_ranger)
[1] "list"`

I created this object, model_ranger, using rsample::vfold_cv()

Comment: It is difficult to test without an example.  May be you try with `bind_rows` approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be accomplished using `split`.  The resulting lists could then be renamed as needed.

```
model_list1 <- split(model_ranger, model_ranger$mtry)
names(model_list1) <- paste0("model_ranger_mtry_", names(model_list1))

model_list2 <- split(model_xgb, model_xgb$nrounds)
names(model_list2) <- paste0("model_xgb_nrounds_", names(model_list2))

> c(model_list1, model_list2)

$model_ranger_mtry_1
splits    id mtry mae
1 <split [72K/18K]> Fold1    1 261
3 <split [72K/18K]> Fold2    1 278
5 <split [72K/18K]> Fold3    1 258
7 <split [72K/18K]> Fold4    1 291
9 <split [72K/18K]> Fold5    1 289

$model_ranger_mtry_2
splits    id mtry mae
2  <split [72K/18K]> Fold1    2 265
4  <split [72K/18K]> Fold2    2 281
6  <split [72K/18K]> Fold3    2 262
8  <split [72K/18K]> Fold4    2 295
10 <split [72K/18K]> Fold5    2 295

$model_xgb_nrounds_100
splits    id nrounds mae
1  <split [72K/18K]> Fold1     100 262
4  <split [72K/18K]> Fold2     100 278
7  <split [72K/18K]> Fold3     100 258
10 <split [72K/18K]> Fold4     100 291
13 <split [72K/18K]> Fold5     100 290

$model_xgb_nrounds_150
splits    id nrounds mae
2  <split [72K/18K]> Fold1     150 262
5  <split [72K/18K]> Fold2     150 278
8  <split [72K/18K]> Fold3     150 258
11 <split [72K/18K]> Fold4     150 291
14 <split [72K/18K]> Fold5     150 290

$model_xgb_nrounds_200
splits    id nrounds mae
3  <split [72K/18K]> Fold1     200 262
6  <split [72K/18K]> Fold2     200 278
9  <split [72K/18K]> Fold3     200 258
12 <split [72K/18K]> Fold4     200 291
15 <split [72K/18K]> Fold5     200 290
```